# Correct artifactID for Scala libraries in Gradle

Tags: scala, gradle

Is there a simple way to follow the Scala convention and append the Scala binary version to the archive name and artifactID of Scala libraries in Gradle? Even better if it is possible to compile the library against multiple Scala versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention that you are referring to isn't built into the Scala plugin, but setting `jar.archiveName` should do the trick. Likewise, building multiple variants isn't currently a first-class feature, but can be achieved in various ways, for example by declaring a separate source set per variant, with each source set pointing to the same source and resource directories. A proof of concept that also handles variants in dependencies (similar to what's offered by sbt) was presented in my [Polyglot Gradle](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/agile-testing/polyglot-gradle-java-groovy-scala-and-beyond) talk at Gradle Exchange 2013.